# Bitbake command to locate path to installed toolchain

Tags: build, compilation, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

What command does one use to find the cross toolchain path installed by bitbake? For example, to locate the patched kernel source tree, one would do ...

```
$ bitbake -e linux | grep '^S='
```

Similarly, what bitbake command can we use to find the cross-compiled toolchain such as "arm-*-linux-*-gcc" used to generate a binary that can run on the target machine?

Comment: how about `echo $CC`?

Comment: I am hoping bitbake would tell me the location of the cross compiler. But the above echo command does not work for me, not even in the sourced oe build env.

Comment: 1. bitbake -c devshell linux-recipe                                                                                    2. echo $CC                                                                                                                       
3. echo $PATH | grep "cross compiler executable file"                                                              Highlited part path is your cross compiler path.

Answer (score 3):

One method to probe for information about the build environment is to use Yocto's "devshell" feature. You can run `bitbake -c devshell RECIPENAME` and then `echo $CC` from within the console that is launched.

Comment: Once in the dev shell, do:    which arm-\*-linux-\*-gcc       to see the location

Comment: like this: <code> which $(echo $CC |awk '{print $1}') </code>